# libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

First I installed python 3.5 and mod_wsgi with python 3.5. It worked fine. Then uninstalled python 3.5 and mod_wsgi .

I again installed python 2.7 and mod_wsgi. Then I used to check `httpd -t` I got the following errors.

I am using easy apache 2.2/2.4, cpanel server having CentOS release 6.7

```
httpd -t
httpd: Syntax error on line 28 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1048577 of /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_global.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache/aast_cms_modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any solutions should be appreciated..

Comment: How are you installing mod_wsgi and how are you then installing it? What steps did you do?

Comment: first i installed python 3.5 by source code compilation to the path /usr/local/

Comment: That doesn't tell me the steps you used to install mod_wsgi and then uninstall it. I want to make sure you are not using the ``pip`` installable mod_wsgi but are using configure/make approach out of mod_wsgi source. To uninstall mod_wsgi in a manual Apache setup as you have, there is no uninstall script, so since you don't seem to have uninstalled the old mod_wsgi using Python 3.5 that is why asking what steps you took to uninstall it.

Comment: installing python steps

Comment: >cd /usr/src 
>wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/(ver)
>tar zxf Python-ver.tgz
>cd python<br/>./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-threads --enable->shared --with-zlib=/usr/include 
> make 
> make altinstall
> mv python-ver.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python-ver.conf
> /sbin/ldconfig
> ln -sfn /usr/local/bin/python-ver /usr/bin/python-ver